# How to use QDBusPendingCallWatcher properly?

Tags: qt, qtdbus

I'm trying to use `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` to watch an async call. Some sample code like this:

```
{
    // interface = new QDBusInterface(...);
    QDBusPendingCall pcall = interface->asyncCall("query");
    QDBusPendingCallWatcher *watcher = new QDBusPendingCallWatcher(pcall, this);
    QObject::connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)), this, SLOT(handler(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)));
}
```

and handler function:

```
void Client::handler(QDBusPendingCallWatcher* call)
{       
    QDBusPendingReply<QString> reply = *call; 
    // do something
}
```

My questions are:

1. It looks like `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` uses [shared data pointer inside](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdbuspendingcall-members.html), is it safe to not manually delete the `watcher` pointer? Just leave the scope and forget it?
2. If I can let the smart pointer of pendingcall to do all the tricks, can I use just one `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` pointer in my class to watch all the async calls? Like this:

   ```
   {
       QDBusPendingCall pcall = interface->asyncCall("query");
       watcher = new QDBusPendingCallWatcher(pcall, this);
       QObject::connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)), this, SLOT(handleOne(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)));

       pcall = interface->asyncCall("anotherQuery");
       watcher = new QDBusPendingCallWatcher(pcall, this);
       QObject::connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)), this, SLOT(handleTwo(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)));
   }
   ```

   Will this makes a disaster? Or should I use multiple pointers for each call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [QDBusPendingCallWatcher documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qdbuspendingcallwatcher.html#details):

> The slot connected to by the above code could be something similar to the following:

```
void MyClass::callFinishedSlot(QDBusPendingCallWatcher *call)
{
    QDBusPendingReply<QString, QByteArray> reply = *call;
    if (reply.isError()) {
        showError();
    } else {
        QString text = reply.argumentAt<0>();
        QByteArray data = reply.argumentAt<1>();
        showReply(text, data);
    }
    call->deleteLater();
}
```

The call of [QObject::deleteLater](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qobject.html#deleteLater) is the key: This means Qt will delete the Object as soon as execution returns to the event loop.

As long as you call `deleteLater` inside `Client::handler(...)`, you don't need to - more precisely you musn't - call `delete watcher;` anywhere. The only thing you have to ensure is that noone uses the object behind `call` after the slot returns.